# Why can't Django via nginx find static files although manage.py findstatic is successful?

Tags: python, django, static

I deployed a Django app via nginx and this worked without any problem for the last few months. However now without any change that I know of Django can't find any static files anymore, so no images are displayed and the django admin page has no stylesheet.

In my `settings.py` I have used the following setting:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')

STATIC_URL = 'http://[ip.of.hosting.server]/[name_of_app]/static/'
```

When I run e.g. `manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 img/logo.png` Django is able to find the image file however in the deployed website the logo is not displayed and I get a `404 file not found` error for the image.

I also tried to run `manage.py collectstatic` however that added no new static files and the files are still not found.

How can this suddenly happen. I have no idea what I might have touched to break

Comment: If you run `debug=false` the static files will be handled by nginx. For this please share your sites-available/<nameOfFile> file inside your nginx server.

Comment: This solved my problem! I actually "tidied up" the location nginx is looking for the files yesterday. Well turns out I was a little to tidy...

Comment: alright then pls set this question to answered :) enjoy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `debug=false` the static files will be handled by nginx. For this please check your sites-available/ file inside your nginx server.